# Is there a way to force IIS to stop arbitrarily switching the .NET Version?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7.5

If you open IIS and click the root node under `Conncetions` (i.e. the server itself) you will see `Change .NET Framework Version` on the right side of the window.

No matter what I do, when I load IIS, it will have switched to `v2.0.50727`, instead of staying on the correct setting `v4.0.30319`.

Is there somewhere that has a configuration file where I can force it to always use the correct version?

Edit: I have only 1 (ONE) application pool that uses version 4.0 in `Integrated` mode. There are 0 (ZERO) application pools that use version 2.0, so there is no clear reason for the version switching itself.

Comment: It uses the version you tell it to use in the application pool. And what do you mean by "open IIS" or "load IIS"?

Comment: There's only one "IIS" window where you can configure all of the settings :P. And yes, I have 0 (ZERO) application pools that use version 2.0. In fact, I have only 1 (ONE) application pool that uses version 4.0, in 'Integrated' mode.

Comment: There's several ways to configure, so it helps to be precise. But that setting doesn't change application pools or sites to different versions. So is your problem just that setting not staying in 4.0? It shouldn't affect anythinf

Comment: I'm uncertain of how much affect the .NET version the root server node is using compared to the version the application pool is using. I just would rather not have a setting arbitrarily changing itself every time the IIS configuration window is launched